# Why do I get an "overflowed on" error when creating an enum with nested generics?

Tags: generics, rust

I need a structure that requires a nested generic inside an enum. This is a minimal example:

```
enum T<A> {
    S(A),
    M(Box<T<Vec<A>>>),
}

fn main() {
    let t = T::M(
        Box::new(
            T::M(
                Box::new(
                    T::S(vec![vec![1], vec![2], vec![3]])
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

The compiler fails with an error:

```
overflowed on T<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<i32>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Why is this happening and is there any way around this?

Comment: What exactly is the type you want to create? Because the one you're defining right now has an infinitely recursive definition.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a finger tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you didn't include the entire error message.  You should always include as much of the error as possible, not just a snippet of it.  For reference, the error is:

```
error[E0320]: overflow while adding drop-check rules for T<i32>
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |     let t = T::M::<i32>(
  |         ^
  |
  = note: overflowed on T<std::vec::Vec<..<std::vec::Vec<i32>>..>>
```

The error itself tells you the problem: the compiler can't generate the drop code for the `T` type.  Consider what the compiler needs to do: in order to destroy a value of type `T<X>`, it needs to be able to destroy either of its variants.  That means code to destroy `X` (for the `S` variant), and code to destroy `Box<T<Vec<X>>>` (for the `M` variant).

To destroy a `Box<T<Vec<X>>>`, it needs code to destroy a `T<Vec<X>>`.  Thus, to destroy a `T<X>`, the compiler also has to generate code to destroy a `T<Vec<X>>`.

Thus, to destroy a `T<Vec<X>>`, the compiler also has to generate code to destroy a `T<Vec<Vec<X>>>`.

Thus, to destroy a `T<Vec<Vec<X>>>`, the compiler also has to generate code to destroy a `T<Vec<Vec<Vec<X>>>>`.

Thus, to destroy a `T<Vec<Vec<Vec<X>>>>`, the compiler also has to generate code to destroy a `T<Vec<Vec<Vec<Vec<X>>>>>`.

Ad infinitum.  The compiler is never able to *stop* needing to generate drop code for an infinitely long sequence of types, so it gives up.  This will happen in any case where destroying a generic type depends on being able to destroy a more complex version of itself.

The solution is to not use `T<Vec<A>>`.  I don't know how you would do that, since I don't know what you're trying to do.  Maybe have more variants?  Maybe use `Vec<T<A>>`?  Maybe have the paylod of `M` be a type parameter instead?

Comment: Specifically I was trying to implement a finger tree. Coming from haskell and scala this is all really confusing and I have a hard time figuring out ways to get around it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to define a finger tree like that in Rust.  Rust has to care about how to deterministically destroy values, and a finger tree is a type with (apparently) infinite complexity.  If you want to do this in Rust, you'd likely have to give up all static guarantees about shape, or redesign it to have a statically fixed depth.

Comment: I'm guessing the only way of doing it is to declare a more general structure and maintain the structure invariant inside the library, at least until rust gets higher kinded types if that ever happens.

Comment: I don't believe HKT will help here.  Assuming Haskell has a tracing garbage collector, it doesn't need to have any drop code, it can just stop pointing to allocations and they get cleaned up automatically.  The problem for Rust is that it *requires* drop code to deallocate the `Box` and `Vec`s.  It has *no choice* but to infinitely expand the type forever.